# How do I get the number of rows equals to a string in MS Reports

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, expression

Simple question but it is killing.

How do I write an expression, that return the number of rows where a column is equal something.

I can get the total rows like this:
`=Count(Fields!Foo.Value)` and `RowNumber("Rapporter")`

But I can't get the number of rows where `Foo` is equal to `someString`

`Foo` is a type string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
=sum(iif(Fields!Foo.Value="Bar", 1, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Where were you two hours ago when I started with this task ;)